# Should I trust the C# compiler to optimize for me or should I use unsafe code in this situation

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have small classes that will be created and destroyed pretty frequently and the vast majority of the time they'll be used briefly and then go out of scope. I'd like for these things to be allocated on the stack.

I can't use structs because my objects need destructors. I just found out about using stackalloc which is unsafe. After reading around I found that c# doesn't necessarily always create classes on the heap. Still if these things are created on the heap it could very well bottleneck my performance. Should I trust c# to allocate them on the stack when it's smart or should I do it myself?

Comment: Start with .NET doing it for you - don't assume it'll be a bottleneck until it is.  You may be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: Perhaps you should implement the solution normally and then analyze the performance of the code before attempting to prematurely optimize. You don't even know if the code is going to be slow yet.

Comment: I have wrote many performance critical applications and (what I have experienced is) I completely trust .NET run-time in doing it's job very well. You really should review every aspect of your code in managed domain and exit that domain if and only if you have good and clear reasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't or don't want to rely on C# memory optimization and want to reuse your objects as much as possible, you could and should simply implement the Object Pool creational pattern.

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool

Good luck